# Composer: conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability

Tags: php, composer-php, phpseclib

I'm trying to run `composer require phpseclib/mcrypt_compat:dev-master` in an empty directory and am getting the following error:

```
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpseclib/mcrypt_compat dev-master -> satisfiable by phpseclib/mcrypt_compat[dev-master].
    - phpseclib/mcrypt_compat dev-master requires phpseclib/phpseclib dev-master -> satisfiable by phpseclib/phpseclib[d
ev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

I do not understand this. https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/composer.json says that the minimum required PHP version is 5.6.1. There are two other libs that are required but Composer isn't saying that those other libs are incompatable - Composer is saying phpseclib/phpseclib is incompatable.

Here's the output I get when I type in `php -v`:

```
PHP 7.0.26 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2017 13:19:37) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

PHP 7.0.26 is newer than PHP 5.6.1, the minimumally required version for phpseclib/phpseclib:dev-master.

Any ideas?

Comment: `composer require vendor/package dev-master` should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a composer.json file with minimum-stability specified:

```
{
     "require": {
         "phpseclib/mcrypt_compat": "dev-master"
      },
     "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability

The minimum stability defaults to stable if not specified.

Comment: You can make the stability change on the command line with `composer config minimum-stability dev`

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my experience:

I was creating one bundle and had `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in my bundle composer.json file. Then when I added new packages, almost all of them were installed with `dev` release.

Later on when I wanted to integrate this bundle into my application, I faced minimum-stability conflict error.

What I did to get rid of this situation:

**In my bundle:**

- Removed `"minimum-stability": "dev"` from composer.json
- Removed all installed packages with `dev` release and `composer require`package name` (without specifying any version), this resulted in installing only stable versions.

**In my application:**

Added the local package again with these settings

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../xyz-auth-bundle"
        }
    ]

"require": {
  ...
  "xyz/auth-bundle": "dev-master"
}
```

`rm -rf var/cache/; composer update;` All went fine.

Some more key points:

**application composer.json:**

- there is no 'minimum-stability` settings
- "type": "project",

**bundle composer.json:**

- There is no `version` specified

Hope this will save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

If you created/updated the composer.json as @Devon mentioned to the required version and see this error still, then it means that you forgot to update the composer.lock :

```
php71 composer.phar update phpseclib/mcrypt_compat --no-progress
```